# What are the elements of the oblateness formula?

Tags: mathematics

Ok, so the formula for calculating oblateness of a planet (in this instance, a gas or ice giant) goes like this:

$\text{Oblateness} = C\frac{R^3}{M P^2}$

I have seen C defined as a constant that depends on the mass distribution of the body in question.  I would like to know how that is determined.  One source just said using multiples of known values (Jupiter or Neptune). What would those values even be?
I am wanting to know what the others are.  I'm guessing it's the following:

R=radius

M=Mass

P=rotation period

I'm not really sure; this is my best guess, since the source doesn't explain it much further.  If anyone knows (which I'm sure someone here does), please either confirm or inform me.  Many thanks!

-M-

Comment: [Equatorial bulge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equatorial_bulge)? (The formula in the article is for the [first flattening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flattening) *f*.)

Comment: Could you post a link to your source (if it is online)?

Comment: The source is a broken link and has not been saved on Internet Archive.  I typed it down verbatim.  The meanings behind R, M, & P are my guesses.  I'm trying to find how oblate the gas giants I have in my systems are.  To do that, I need to know what values to put in, and if this is even the correct formula for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Mike What is the oblateness?

Comment: I have a gas giant of 242.11 earth masses, a density of 1.576 g per cubic cm., and a rotation period of 10.57 hours.  WHAT I AM TRYING TO FIND OUT IS:  Does this object look more like Jupiter (roundish), or Saturn (not-so round), and how do I calculate this myself.

Comment: @Daron: Oblateness is another word for [flattening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flattening). Earth is an oblate spheroid with an oblateness, or flattening, of about 1:298 or 0.34%.

Comment: @AlexP Thanks for telling me.

Comment: @Mike Those formulae appear [here](https://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/Oblateness.html) too but they don't bother to say what the oblateness constant means. They just define $q = $ your stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you want is:

$$\frac{a-b}{b} = \frac{5}{4}\frac{(2\pi/T)^2 R^3}{GM}$$

Where:

$a$ is the (larger) equatorial radius.

$b$ is the (smaller) polar radius.

$T$ is the time for one revolution.

$R = (b+2a)/3$ is the mean radius.

$M$ is the mass of the planet.

$G$ is Newton's constant.

The formula is derived in [this thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8074/why-is-the-earth-so-fat) where it seems to agree with the experimental numbers for Earth. This is good for you because it suggests we can indeed ignore how the planet is denser in the middle. See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equatorial_bulge) and their source [[8]](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newton/node109.html).

Comment: So, what you're saying is my mean radius (which in this case, I'll say is 60421 km,) will be number crunched into a new set? Very nice.  Now I have to figure out how to do maths with Newton's Constant...I thank you, sir!

Comment: Also, where can I enter this formula?  I've tried a few calculators and Wolfram Alpha.  It never lets itself get entered as we see presented here.

Comment: @Mike: Microsoft Excel or Google Sheets or LibreOffice Calc.

Comment: Officially stumped.  I could never figure out how to use the gravitational constant, so I avoided any calculations with it. I managed to get it entered into Wolfram Alpha, but it came back with some ridiculously high number that I couldn't make use of.  So I guess I probably need to express the numbers correctly in SI units?

Comment: @Mike Yes yes yes. You need everything in SI units. kilos, seconds, metres, etc. Then Newton's constant is just a number. [If I have input everything right the formula seems to give 0.42% rather than the real 0.3% ish number.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nm2ltkyd16) Eh,  close enough.

Comment: Using those numbers (thank you very much, again) I get a number of .0779...This planet may look a little like Saturn, but not as squished.  Neat.

Comment: @Mike I don't know about you but I cannot reliably eyeball the difference between an 8% and 10% oblated spheroid.

Comment: Saturn is like .09-something.  So, I think it (the planet I'm working on) may have a slight squish to it, enough so that you can tell it is not exactly round.

Comment: Just did a quick test in GIMP to compare the two.  8% vs 10% seems slight, but it is noticeable.  My world will look just a teensy, tiny little bit more round than Saturn...but not by much.  Compared to a round object, it is decidedly not round.

Comment: @Mike Good. Now get on with writing your novel!